# How to open a Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, Smart device program on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've developed a program  in `Visual Studio 2008, Smart Device`, it works and i have not -too much- problems with it!

But now I uninstalled `MVS2008` and `installed MVS2012`, the problem here is: I can't open mi `MVS2088` project...

`MVS2012` says: `"Algunos proyectos no se admiten o necesitan modificaciones que afecatn al rendimiento de los mismos para abirse en esta versión de Visual Studio"...`

**Any idea about what could I do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing, you must reinstall VS2008, VS2010 and upwards does not have support for old Windows Mobile applications.

Comment: Yes ,it's a shame but true

Comment: Yep, really. Check out Microsoft's VisualStudio change notes